# The request does not have valid authentication credentials

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I need to get access the Analytics Reporting API V4. I followed below documentation in order to get this done.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php

But from the beginning I got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message ' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\ga_test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php
>   on line 118
>
> Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "The
>   request does not have valid authentication credentials.", "errors": [
>   { "message": "The request does not have valid authentication
>   credentials.", "domain": "global", "reason": "unauthorized" } ],
>   "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } in
>   C:\wamp64\www\ga_test\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php
>   on line 118 Call Stack

How to fix this issue. I followed all steps as per doc and exact php code.

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);

function initializeAnalytics()
{
  // Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  return $analytics;
}

function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "xxxxxxx";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}

function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count( $metricHeaders ) && $j < count( $metrics ); $j++) {
        $entry = $metricHeaders[$j];
        $values = $metrics[$j];
        print("Metric type: " . $entry->getType() . "\n" );
        for ( $valueIndex = 0; $valueIndex < count( $values->getValues() ); $valueIndex++ ) {
          $value = $values->getValues()[ $valueIndex ];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $value . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help to resolve this issue. When var_dump $analytics I got this result,

```
C:\wamp64\www\ga_test\HelloAnalytics.php:25:
object(Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting)[2]
  public 'reports' => 
    object(Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Resource_Reports)[4]
      private 'stackParameters' (Google_Service_Resource) => 
        array (size=10)
          'alt' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'fields' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'trace' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'userIp' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'quotaUser' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'data' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'mimeType' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'uploadType' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'mediaUpload' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'prettyPrint' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      private 'rootUrl' (Google_Service_Resource) => string 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/' (length=42)
      private 'client' (Google_Service_Resource) => 
        object(Google_Client)[3]
          private 'auth' => null
          private 'http' => null
          private 'cache' => null
          private 'token' => null
          private 'config' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          private 'logger' => null
          private 'deferExecution' => boolean false
          protected 'requestedScopes' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      private 'serviceName' (Google_Service_Resource) => string 'analyticsreporting' (length=18)
      private 'servicePath' (Google_Service_Resource) => string '' (length=0)
      private 'resourceName' (Google_Service_Resource) => string 'reports' (length=7)
      private 'methods' (Google_Service_Resource) => 
        array (size=1)
          'batchGet' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
  public 'batchPath' => null
  public 'rootUrl' => string 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/' (length=42)
  public 'version' => string 'v4' (length=2)
  public 'servicePath' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'availableScopes' => null
  public 'resource' => null
  private 'client' (Google_Service) => 
    object(Google_Client)[3]
      private 'auth' => null
      private 'http' => null
      private 'cache' => null
      private 'token' => null
      private 'config' => 
        array (size=22)
          'application_name' => string 'Hello Analytics Reporting' (length=25)
          'base_path' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com' (length=26)
          'client_id' => string 'xxxx' (length=72)
          'client_secret' => string 'xxxxxx' (length=24)
          'redirect_uri' => null
          'state' => null
          'developer_key' => string '' (length=0)
          'use_application_default_credentials' => boolean false
          'signing_key' => null
          'signing_algorithm' => null
          'subject' => null
          'hd' => string '' (length=0)
          'prompt' => string '' (length=0)
          'openid.realm' => string '' (length=0)
          'include_granted_scopes' => null
          'login_hint' => string '' (length=0)
          'request_visible_actions' => string '' (length=0)
          'access_type' => string 'online' (length=6)
          'approval_prompt' => string 'auto' (length=4)
          'retry' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'cache_config' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'token_callback' => null
      private 'logger' => null
      private 'deferExecution' => boolean false
      protected 'requestedScopes' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' (length=50)
  public 'serviceName' => string 'analyticsreporting' (length=18)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add relevant code and more details to the question.

Comment: @Janaka Dombawela Hi I have added relevant code

Comment: `/service-account-credentials.json` should have the authentication key which you have to take from google developer console. Have you created a project in google developer console?

Comment: Yes I created a project and download that json file which include client id and other stuff. Did you manage to get this work?

Comment: Did you add the service account as a user in google analytics? can you give us a var dump of $analytics

Comment: @ DaImTo Sorry for the delay. I have edited my code which returns vardump variable

Comment: I found the issue. I use wrong downloaded field. We need to use json file which creates during service creation